# Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) & Doctrine 2 with dynamic form using a ManyToMany association

Tags: forms, collections, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

What is the best practice for using forms to updating roles who have multiple permissions?

My **roles** table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | admin |
|  2 | user  |
+----+-------+
```

My **permissions** table:

```
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | createUser |
|  2 | updateUser |
|  3 | createRole |
|  4 | updateRole |
+----+------------+
```

My ManyToMany association table, **role_permission**:

```
+---------+---------------+
| role_id | permission_id |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 |             1 |
|       1 |             2 |
|       1 |             3 |
|       1 |             4 |
|       2 |             2 |
+---------+---------------+
```

My goal is to show all roles with a radiobutton and dynamically show the associated permissions with checkboxes.

Image of my problem:
[image](http://puu.sh/gRxRT/ce3e635e27.png)

When I click the admin role, the permissions aren't updated with the selected role (of course). This brings me back to my question: what is the best practice to dynamically show the right permissions for the selected role using ZF2 + Doctrine 2?

This is how I generate my form:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class EditRoleForm extends Form implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{

    private $editRoleInputFilter;
    private $entityManager;
    private $roleRepository;
    private $permissionRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
        parent::__construct('editRole');
        $this->editRoleInputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->roleRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Authorization\Entity\Role');
        $this->permissionRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Authorization\Entity\Permission');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'roles',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectRadio',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Roles',
                'label_attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-12'
                ),
                'object_manager' => $this->entityManager,
                'target_class' => 'Authorization\Entity\Role',
                'property' => 'name',
                'is_method' => true,
                'find_method' => array(
                    'name' => 'findAll',
                    'params' => array(
                        'orderBy' => array('id' => 'ASC'),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'permissions',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Permissions',
                'label_attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'col-sm-12'
                ),
                'object_manager' => $this->entityManager,
                'target_class' => 'Authorization\Entity\Permission',
                'property' => 'name',
                'is_method' => true,
                'find_method' => array(
                    'name' => 'findAll',
                    'params' => array(
                        'orderBy' => array('id' => 'ASC'), // Sorting won't work
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Update role',
                'id' => 'submitEditRoleButton',
                'class' => 'btn btn-white'
            ),
        ));

        // assign input filters and validators
        $this->editRoleInputFilter->add(array(
            'name' => 'permissions',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
        ));


        $this->setInputFilter($this->editRoleInputFilter);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to link the checkboxes to the selected radiobuttons.

Comment: Normally a form represents a single row (one role in you case). I belevie this is hard to be solved with the zf2 buid in forms and model system(docrtine in you case). The best in you case would be so preload this data with javascript and change them on the fly. Ps. Doctrine2 is a performance killer for php app.

Comment: I fixed this by passing my rol_permission table to JQuery and created a function that checks the right check boxes when a radio button is clicked.